# Calculate percentage in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have the below requirements.

Test data has the following values.

I need to find the percentage of each of the characters out of the total.

I have tried with the below query , but not to success.

```
Ex:
W
H
U
U
H
W
U
W
W
H
W
U
H
H
H
U
W
W
W
H

data = LOAD 'location of test data';

grp = GROUP data BY data.$0; // considering only 1 field in this csv.

result = FOREACH grp GENERATE group, COUNT(data.$0)/SUM(data.$0);
```

Since the fields are `chararrays`, I am not able to do the sum of the fields.

Is there an alternate to find one?

If I use a GROUP ALL, followed by COUNT(data.$0), I get the total number of entries.

If I use a GROUP of the field, followed by COUNT(data.$0), I get the individual count.

Here i need the percentage of this individual count by the sum.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here i need the percentage of this individual count by the sum.

To do this, you would need to run two Pig Operations I believe - 
1) First as you said get the individual counts in one relation

```
W 8
H 7 
U 5
```

2) Second, you count all the elements as you mentioned earlier in one relation

```
total 20
```

3) You then need to CROSS the relations obtained in first and two (CROSS) so that you have a new relation like this

```
W 8 20
H 7 20
U 5 20
```

4) Post this, you can calculate the percentage that you wanted.

***Update***

Below is the Pig script that I came up with.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' using PigStorage('\n');
--DUMP A;
B = GROUP A by $0;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group, COUNT(A.$0);
--DUMP C;
D = GROUP A ALL;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,COUNT(A.$0);
DUMP E;
DESCRIBE C;
DESCRIBE E;
F = CROSS C,E;
G = FOREACH F GENERATE $0,$1,$3,($1*100/$3);
DESCRIBE G;
DUMP G;
```

Comment: grp1 = GROUP data BY $0;
individual = FOREACH grp1 GENERATE group, COUNT(data.$0);
grp2= GROUP data ALL;
sumation = FOREACH grp2 GENERATE group, COUNT(data.$0);
result = JOIN individual BY data.$0 FULL OUTER , sumation BY data.$0

This is giving an error while processing "Scalar has more than one output..."..

Comment: Could you check if the dumps for individual and summation dump data as expected.

Comment: Cool, could you please mark this as an answer then?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do that manually,

something like

```
data = foreach data generate *, ((B=='b1')?1:0) AS dummy_b1;
data = foreach data generate *, mean(dummy_b1) AS percentage;
```